# Applicability of Fourier transform to periodic signals?

Tags: fourier-transform

Can we use Fourier Transform for periodic signals or only we can use fourier series with periodic signals?
I am asking this question because I read on page 301 of alex palamides as shown highlighted in attached photo[image]

Comment: It's applicable, but you get Dirac deltas as a result. This raises many mathematical issues and some authors prefer to avoid them. IMO, the FT of a periodic signal doesn't add anything meaningful that is not contained in its FS .

Comment: [This answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/24242/4298) shows how the Fourier transform of a periodic signal is computed (from its Fourier series coefficients).